# Is there a way to pass data to jobs with dashing?

Tags: ruby, dashing

I am working on a dashboard to display a few data points on a specific server. Obtaining this data requires non-trivial resources, so ideally it would only happen if there is a widget that is actively listening to it. Is this doable with dashing ? Example:

User surfs to /server-info?server_id=1234

This returns an HTML page with data-id="server-info-1234" AND somehow alerts the jobs/server-info.rb to start collecting data on "1234". Ideally once the tab is closed, the job is notified.

In essence, is there a way for the web views to send data/events to the jobs ?

Comment: Hi, I need something very similar. Have you found a way to achieve that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No not really, however it may be possible to solve this another way.

Inside your job, once you `require 'sinatra'` you can see how many active connections are running like this: `Sinatra::Application.settings.connections`.

So, do something like this:

```
require 'sinatra'

current = 0
SCHEDULER.every '30s' do
  if Sinatra::Application.settings.connections.length > 0
    current = doMyCostlyOperation()
  end

  send_event('value', { current: current })
end
```